# How to check the model of the wifi chip on Android 9?

Tags: wi-fi, motorola-moto-g

I'd like to know if there is an easy way (if possible without using the terminal) to get the model of the wifi chip on my Android 9 (Motorola moto g6 play). I found only very old methods, some of them based on apps that do not exist anymore.

Comment: According to gsmarena there are two versions of that device known. Each variant uses a different chipset with different Wifi capabilities: https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g6_play-9002.php Which one is yours? You should be able to use an hardware info app from Play Store to find out which version you have.

Comment: Hello @Robert thank you very much for your useful comment. I have the one with the Qualcomm Snapdragon 430 1.40 GHz (architecture 8x ARM Cortex-A53). If possible tell me also a general way to identify the wifi chip on any smartphone please.

Comment: As the MSM8937 Snapdragon 430 comes with built-in Wifi then this is the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Robert . Do you know any application able to retrieve the same information?

Comment: As nearly all Smartphone CPUs also contain the Wifi chip you just need an hardware info app that displays the CPU type.

Comment: @Robert is there the possibility to know if it supports dual band?

Comment: Not by the chip name itself. I do remember that for some chips even by looking at the spec it can get difficult. Usually standards like 802.11a or 802.11ac indicate that 5GHz is supported but as far as I remember there were a few counterexamples. And some other standards like 802.11n and 802.11ax can be used in 2.4 and 5GHz so you don't know if the device has 5Ghz or not.

Comment: @Robert Here https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon-430-mobile-platform you can read **Wi-Fi Spectral Bands: 2.4 GHz, 5 GHz**, but my smartphone is able to see only the 2.4 GHz...it's strange